# Rails Brakeman SQL injection warning when using Arel syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection, arel, brakeman

In my Rails 3.2 app, [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/) 1.8.3 raises a High confidence SQL injection warning for the following code in a model:

**micropost.rb**

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
  followed_user_ids = Relationship.select(:followed_id).
                      where("follower_id = :user_id").
                      to_sql
  where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
        user_id: user.id)
end
```

However, when I change the code to not use Arel syntax, no warning is raised:

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
  followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                       WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
  where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
        user_id: user.id)
end
```

Is this a false positive, or something to do with Arel syntax or the `to_sql` method...?  I don't understand what the difference is between the actual code that gets executed in the two examples that would warrant the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a false positive.

In this situation, Brakeman knows `Relationship` is a model, and that `select` and `where` are query methods. So it assumes `Relationship.select(...).where(...).to_sql` is a record attribute (and potentially dangerous). It shouldn't, though, since `to_sql` just generates the SQL code for the query as you mentioned. I'll fix this.

The second version of course does not warn because you are interpolating a string literal.

Comment: Best answer I could have hoped for!  Thanks very much!